# Change name of card on Trello with API by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, trello

I have this code in Javascript to modify the name of a Trello card through its API, and I do not get it, any ideas?

Documentation API Trello: https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#cardsid-1

Code:

```
var onAuthorize = function() {
    updateLoggedIn();
    $("#output").empty();

    Trello.members.get("me", function(member){
        $("#fullName").text(member.fullName);

    var id= "5ab7c3c631a2019c50b701c8";
//Change name
         Trello.put('/boards/me/cards/5ab7c3c631a2019c50b701c8/name?value=nombrecito',function () {alert("funciona bien")}, function(err) {alert( "mal")});

    });

    };


var updateLoggedIn = function() {
    var isLoggedIn = Trello.authorized();
    $("#loggedout").toggle(!isLoggedIn);
    $("#loggedin").toggle(isLoggedIn);        
};

var logout = function() {
    Trello.deauthorize();
    updateLoggedIn();
};

Trello.authorize({
    interactive:false,
    success: onAuthorize
});

$("#connectLink")
.click(function(){
    Trello.authorize({
        type: "popup",
        success: onAuthorize
    })
});

$("#disconnect").click(logout);
```

The error I get is [object Object]

I have also tried with this URL:`'cards/5ab7c3c631a2019c50b701c8/name?value=nombrecito'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Trello.put` URL is a little off.

Fix the `Trello.put` with...

`Trello.put("/boards/mecards/5ab7c3c631a2019c50b701c8/name?value=nombrecito", function () {}, function(err) {alert(err)});`

Comment: I realized after posting, I modified the URL and I still do

Comment: There is a typo now in the Trello.put.  `Trello.put('/borads` should be `Trello.put('/boards`

Comment: I made a mistake to modify here, that's not the problem, I was trying with board, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the live example on the documentation page? It's not that complicated and something like this.

```
const API_KEY = 'your key';
const TOKEN = 'your token';

let id = 'your trello card id';
let newName = 'a new name what you want';

var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});
xhr.open("PUT", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/"+id+"?name="+newName+"&key="+API_KEY+"&token="+TOKEN);
xhr.send(data);
```

I've tested with my own cards and it works very well.

Comment: Yes, it was finally my solution, my challenge was not to use the token or the api key in the call, but I tried this and it did, thanks

Comment: I have a problem with this form, I want to get the token using var t = Trello.token (); but it returns a token different from the one I get on the Trello page, I have verified that the API-KEY is the same on both sites, which may be happening? Thanks